# Problema com código SQL na anotação @Query em java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Estou tentando realizar um comando através do Inner Join em uma anotação `@Query` em Java, porém acontece um erro. O código funciona normalmente quando a realizo uma consulta SQL sem usar o Inner Join. Segue os códigos utilizados:

**MÉTODO CRIADO NO REPOSITORY/INTERFACE PRODUTO:**

```
@Query(value = "select tb_produto.id, tb_produto.marca, tb_produto.nome from tb_produto 
inner join tb_tipo_eletro on tb_produto.tipoeletro_id = tb_tipo_eletro.id 
where tipoeletro_id = :id and preco <= :preco", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Produto> filtragem (@Param("id") long id, @Param("preco" ) float preco);
```

**PUBLICAÇÃO DO MÉTODO NA CLASSE CONTROLLER PRODUTO:**

```
@GetMapping("/filtragem/{id}/{preco}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Produto>> filtragem(@PathVariable long id, @PathVariable float preco) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(produto.filtragem(id, preco));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer a query assim:

```
@Query(value = "select p.id, p.marca, p.nome " +
    "from tb_produto as p " +
    "inner join tb_tipo_eletro as te on p.tipoeletro_id = te.id " +
    "where p.tipoeletro_id = :id and preco <= :preco", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Produto> filtragem(@Param("id") long id, @Param("preco") float preco);
```

Um detalhe que é importante validar é se essa coluna `preco` existe nas duas colunas. Se existe é importante colocar o alias da tabela na qual deseja fazer a query. Ou seja, ficaria assim:

`p.preco` ou `te.preco`

Se for possível, seria importante postar o erro que está acontecendo aqui também (message, stacktrace e etc..) para ajudar a identificar o erro